# How to pass a method from angular (typescript file) to electron

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I want to pass a method from my typescript file to electron main js.
Is it possible?

My code in my electron page:

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    globalShortcut.register('Control+U', () => {
      console.log('Electron loves global shortcuts!')
    })
  }).then(createWindow)
```